# Cannot understant why ISP speed is slow thru wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet

I have a 100mbps internet connection. ISP's modem is in bridged mode, behind a TP-Link router connected to computers.

Running speedtest on a wired PC, I get almost the full 100Mbps download speed but on my laptop, the speed is ~50mbps.

Router wifi is configured to 802.11 bgn mixed, 40 mhz and, the OS wifi status window says wifi speed is 150mbps.

Why cannot I get the full 100mbps download speed on wireless?

Comment: [Wifi is slower than Ethernet cable connection?](//superuser.com/q/417469)

Comment: Yes, WiFi TCP throughput is usually less than Ethernet cable connection.  When windows status says 150Mbps, it's actually an 802.11 Rate of 150 (MCS7) at 40MHz SGI.  In a pristine environment, you usually get 50% of the actual rate (~75Mbps), because of the added overhead when using WiFi.  In a open scenario, with added distance and obstructions, 50Mbps of TCP throughput sounds about right.

Comment: mbps or Mbps?  There is a magnitude difference between those two units. You should edit your question to clarify the units.  **Unusual for a connection to be rate in megabits per second**

Comment: @Ramhound, I think you mean Mbps/mbps vs MBps.  When Mbps/mbps represent Megabit per second and MBps represents Megabytes per second.  You are correct though, there is a magnitude of difference between the two.

Comment: @pythonian so basically all is ok but wifi overhead is high and that's the "why" it is slower?

Comment: @MauroH.Leggieri YesSir.

Comment: @pythonian Darn You Autocorrect!  The author should still clarify the units

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, WiFi TCP throughput is usually less than Ethernet cable connection. When windows status says 150Mbps, it's actually an 802.11 Rate of 150 (MCS7) at 40MHz SGI. In a pristine environment, you usually get 50% of the actual rate (~75Mbps), because of the added overhead when using WiFi. In a open scenario, with added distance and obstructions, 50Mbps of TCP throughput sounds about right.

Answer (score -1):

1. Can you do a sort of test on your own network? like, copy a large file from your laptop to a NAS or another PC...see how fast it goes & see point No.2.
2. Divide by 8 (to get 'megs per second.)
   so if a result says you got 75mbps, you divide it by 8 to get MB's.

   75 / 8 =  9.30MB per second
   150 / 8 = 18.75MB per second
   its weird, but it works, it makes it more human-readable to us.
3. not all wifi hardware is equal. some use "software" or piggyback off the CPU to do wifi, where-as the good stuff has it's own onboard CPU and ram to do it which is of course, faster!